# Changing template command to allow for two affiliations

Tags: ieeeconf, renewcommand

I'm following a [conference template](https://www.2022apsursi.org/papers.php) and there is the command `\author[orgN]{First A. Author}` which allows to include the author name and its affiliation. I was asked by one of the co-authors to add a second affiliation but having the command `\author[orgN, orgN+1]{First A. Author}` returns a `(??)` superscript instead of `(1),(2)`.

From the template that you can find the link these are the functions that create such commands

```tex
\newcounter{author}
\renewcommand{\author}[2][]{
   \stepcounter{author}
   \@namedef{author@\theauthor}{#2}
   \@namedef{authorlabel@\theauthor}{#1}
}

\newcounter{address}
\newcommand{\address}[2][]{
   \stepcounter{address}
   \@namedef{address@\theaddress}{#2}
   \@namedef{addresslabel@\theaddress}{#1}
}
```

Whereas an author and its affiliation would be created as such

```tex
% authors and affiliations
% the organization option [orgN] associates the authors with the
% proper address
\author[org1]{First A. Author}
\author[org1]{Second B. Author}
\author[org2]{Third C. Author}

% each address must have a unique identifier in the option field
\address[org1]{The University of Here, Anywhere, VA 12345, USA, http://www.here.edu}
\address[org2]{The Next Company, Neverland, WA 54321, USA (author@next.com)}
```

I'm sorry if this simple, I use LaTeX very casually usually following templates without much problem.

Comment: Dear John, this creates a ton of uncontrolled sequences when using this idea. I don't know how to best show a log of this (this is currently an overleaf project).

Answer (score 0):

I defined the command `\addressxtra` to accommodate two addresses.

```
\addressxtra{< unique identifier>}
{<first address>} % 
{<second address>}%
```

like

```
\addressxtra{org2}
{The Next Company, Neverland, WA 54321, USA (author@next.com)} % first address
{Also: Department of Chemistry, Unknown University, Unknown Town}% second address
```

with two flavors:

**(1)**

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\addressxtra}[3]{%  first option <<<<<<<<<<<<<
    \address[#1]{#2\par ${}^{(\thec@address)}$\,#3}
    }
\makeatother
```

[image: a]

or **(2)**

```
\newcommand{\addressxtra}[3]{% second option <<<<<<<<<<
    \address[#1]{#2\par\phantom{(2)} #3}
}
```

with this output:

[image: c]

Put any of the definitions in the preamble.

```
\title{Template for AP-S/USNC-URSI Two-Page Summary }

\author[org1]{First A. Author}
\author[org1]{Second B. Author}
\author[org2]{Third C. Author}

\address[org1]{The University of Here, Anywhere, VA 12345, USA, http://www.here.edu}


%% **************************************** added
%\makeatletter
%\newcommand{\addressxtra}[3]{%  first option <<<<<<<<<<<<<
%   \address[#1]{#2\par ${}^{(\thec@address)}$\,#3}
%   }
%\makeatother

\newcommand{\addressxtra}[3]{% second option <<<<<<<<<<
    \address[#1]{#2\par\phantom{(2)} #3}
}

\addressxtra{org2}
{The Next Company, Neverland, WA 54321, USA (author@next.com)} % first address
{Also: Department of Chemistry, Unknown University, Unknown Town}% second address
%% **************************************** 

\begin{document}

\newmaketitle
```

Answer (score 0):

I like the idea from Simon Dispa, but I then realized there was a very easy workaround.

One can simply do `\author[orgN]{First. A. Author$^{(N+1)}}$` which would show up like so:

[image]

Then it is just a matter of re-arranging accordingly, since if you add an address it shows up even if not used on the `\author` command.